# Swift effect, tilt D Pad controls

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

Working on an iOS game right now using swift, and am having trouble trying to get the effect i want.

Basically, i have a Dpad for moving around, it's simply one sprite node that displays the image and then some transparent rectangles overtop to trigger the actions.

I want the dpad to tilt downwards slightly in the direction the user taps and holds, to simulate feedback like on a real life direction pad. And by downwards, i mean some kind of 3d flip effect, but only applied slightly. Does that make sense? Is that possible with any kind of actions on an `SKSpriteNode`?

I've tried using `SKAction.scaleX` since when you set it to -1 it fully flips the node, but does an actual scale when it's not -1.

Any tips or advice is greatly appriciated!

Comment: Have you tried the answers described here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20125224/how-to-rotate-an-skspritenode-around-the-nodes-y-axis

Comment: ahhh damn, looks like i'm just going to have to make a sprite atlas out of it and load different sprites i think

Comment: Or you could use the second answer where you create its own scene so that you can "morph" it using the UIView 3d transform methods.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rotate an SKSpriteNode around the node's Y-axis?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20125224/how-to-rotate-an-skspritenode-around-the-nodes-y-axis)